Finding residue of $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2-1} \sin\frac{1}{z^2 + z^4}$ at $z = 0$
Trying to find the residue for  $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2-1}  \sin\frac{1}{z^2 + z^4}$ at $z = 0$.
I am concentrating on the sin term in particular.
What is a good strategy to approach this? One thing I tried is to decompose into partial fractions and use a trig identity (along with evenness / oddness of sin and cos) e.g:
$$
\sin\frac{1}{z^2 + z^4} 
= \sin(\frac{1}{z^2} - \frac{1}{1 + z^2})
= \sin(\frac{1}{z^2})\cos(\frac{1}{1 + z^2}) - \cos(\frac{1}{z^2})\sin(\frac{1}{1 + z^2})
$$
I could try and develop taylor / laurent series from here but not sure this is the right direction as the expressions are still quite involved. Any hints or directions would be appreciated!

Notice that $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{z^2-1}\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{z^2+z^4}\right)$ is an even function,  as $$f(z)=\dfrac{1}{z^2-1}\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{z^2+z^4}\right)=\dfrac{1}{(-z)^2-1}\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{(-z)^2+(-z)^4}\right)=f(-z)$$
It is well known that the Laurent Series of an even function around $0$ only has even terms. In particular, the coefficient of $z^{-1}$, which is the residue of $f$ at $0$, is $0$.

aha.. thank you!
